# Adding Keyword to Hint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell, stored-procedures

I am looking to write a PowerShell script that would loop through the contents of a SQL script file looking for lines that contain TABLE HINTS where it does not have a WITH statement.

**Example:**

- `SELECT * FROM dbo.Table (NOLOCK)`
- `SELECT * FROM dbo.Table (INDEX=PK_Table)`
- `SELECT * FROM dbo.Table (NOLOCK,INDEX=PK_Table)`
- `SELECT * FROM dbo.Table (INDEX=PK_Table,NOLOCK)`

I'd like to write a powershell script which looks for those hints and adds `WITH` before the TABLE HINT.

So they look like the following:

- `SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WITH (NOLOCK)`
- `SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WITH (INDEX=PK_Table)`
- `SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WITH (NOLOCK,INDEX=PK_Table)`
- `SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WITH (INDEX=PK_Table,NOLOCK)`

So far I've got the following:

```bsh
foreach ($str in Get-Content "d:\script.sql") {
    if ([regex]::IsMatch($str, "\({0,1}NOLOCK\)|\(,NOLOCK\{0,1}\)","IgnoreCase")) {
        $strReplace = [regex]::Replace($str, "\({0,1}NOLOCK\)|\(,NOLOCK\{0,1}\)", "WITH $1")
        write $strReplace
    }
}
```

However it does not insert the `WITH` into the line and keeps the match and the line.

This would also have to handle scripts like the following:

```sql
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.* FROM dbo.Table1 Table1 (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 Table2 (INDEX=PK_Table2, NOLOCK)
ON (Table2.Id = Table1.Id)
```

WITH THE SUGGESTION BELOW: I used the following:

```html
$expr = "(?=\([^)]*(?=(NOLOCK|INDEX=|INDEX\())[^)]*\))(?<!WITH\s+)"

if ([regex]::IsMatch($str, "(?=\([^)]*(?=(NOLOCK|INDEX=|INDEX\())[^)]*\))","IgnoreCase")) {
        $replaced = $str -replace $expr,"WITH "
```

Comment: String parsing will be fragile unless the SQL statements are consistently structured.  Consider using a T-SQL script DOM: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to convert 1000+ procedures that are potentially written without the WITH keyword in place, to bring them up to compilance with new versions of SQL Server. I cannot find any examples of using a script DOM to repair non-compilant procedures.

Comment: Also note that we use Redgate for SQL Formatting and source control so they are always in the same format.

Comment: Perhaps the time would be better spent reviewing these queries to determine if these hints, especially `NOLOCK` (the percveived need for which is **greatly** reduced with `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` isolation level, are even required. If you're trying to get in compliance with a newer version of SQL Server, other changes in the engine may obviate the need for those hints.

Comment: thanks Alroc, we are trying to script very old databases that are running and upgrading them, however we need to get the database into the highest compatibility level to do our analysis on feature changes of the SQL versions and make the necessary changes where required through unit testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following expession would work, at least with your input samples. There is no guarantee that it will

- match all the things it should
- match none of the things it shouldn't
- not wreak havoc on your SQL code

You need to test very carefully for all three situations. Also think of edge cases.

```
$sample = "
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table (NOLOCK)
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table (INDEX=PK_Table)
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table (NOLOCK,INDEX=PK_Table)
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table (INDEX=PK_Table,NOLOCK)


SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WITH (NOLOCK)
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WITH (INDEX=PK_Table)
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WITH (NOLOCK,INDEX=PK_Table)
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WITH (INDEX=PK_Table,NOLOCK)
"

$expr = "(?=\([^()]*(?=\b(?:NOLOCK|INDEX)\b)[^()]*\))(?<!WITH\s+)"

$sample -replace $expr,"WITH "
```

result:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WITH (NOLOCK)
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WITH (INDEX=PK_Table)
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WITH (NOLOCK,INDEX=PK_Table)
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WITH (INDEX=PK_Table,NOLOCK)


SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WITH (NOLOCK)
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WITH (INDEX=PK_Table)
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WITH (NOLOCK,INDEX=PK_Table)
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WITH (INDEX=PK_Table,NOLOCK)
```

Regex high-level break-down:

```
(?=\([^()]*(?=\b(?:NOLOCK|INDEX)\b)[^()]*\))  # a position followed by the words "INDEX" or
                                              # "NOLOCK" somewhere in parentheses
                                              # (add more keywords if you want)
(?<!WITH\s+)                                  # the same position must not be preceded by "WITH"
```

These two look-around conditions pinpoint the location of a missing WITH keyword. After that inserting it with the `-replace` operator is simple.

Detailed break-down:

```
(?=                      # start zero-width look-ahead
  \(                     #   "("
  [^()]*                 #   any character except "(" and ")", repeat
  \b                     #   a word boundary
  (?=                    #   start non-matching group
    (?:NOLOCK|INDEX)     #     "NOLOCK" or "INDEX"
  )                      #   end group
  \b                     #   a word boundary
  [^()]*                 #   any character except "(" and ")", repeat
  \)                     #   ")"
)                        # end look-ahead
(?<!                     # start zero-width negative look-behind
  WITH                   #   "WITH"
  \s+                    #   any number of whitespace
)                        # end look-begind
```

---

That being said, your script can be written more elegantly as

```
(Get-Content -Raw D:\script.sql) -replace $expr,"WITH "
```

you can also redirect the output into a new file

```
(Get-Content -Raw D:\script.sql) -replace $expr,"WITH " > script_processed.sql
```

The -Raw parameter reads the file as one big string, not line-wise. Line-wise processing would be not useful in this situation.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, Regex is a pain for me, if you had **(INDEX(PK_Table),NOLOCK)** how would you include that?

Comment: What makes you think that this is not included?

Comment: Currently nothing, I did not test that specific example and posted the question, if it works that is great. Will feed back

Comment: Take the time to read the answer thoroughly. I've broken the regex down into tiny bits for a reason, after all.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, I've run the test against a script and for this example line  **(Code = substring(@Reference, IDStartIndex+1, IDLength) between StartRange and EndRange))** it changed it to **WITH (Code = substringWITH (@Reference, IDStartIndex+1, IDLength) between StartRange and EndRange))** It therefore looks like an issue with the brackets.

Comment: This is the reason why modifying data structures (and source code is a data structure) with regex is so problematic. It simply does not work properly. This is true for regex on XML/HTML, it's true for regex on JSON and it's true for regex on SQL. In fact, I should not have answered this question in the first place, because I knew that it would end like this.

Comment: I will not help you "fix" the regex. There is no fix for this kind of issue. You have a copy and you can try to dabble with it until you have something that does not do the wrong thing with your code, but you are on your own. And it's highly likely that you will be wasting your time. Your time is much better invested evaluating the SQL parser that Dan suggested in the comments above.

Comment: Thank you Tomalak for your help, you have already set myself on the right track. I have already altered the script to fix that particular issue and it is working it a treat. I am not looking to just hit on the script I am comparing the two scripts with a beyond compare tool to accept the changes. This script reduces the need to go through every line and validate the changes.

Comment: FWIW, I've made one last change to the expression that effectively prevents it from matching nested parentheses and limits matches to full keywords. It works for the situation you mentioned, but from here on out you are on your own. Regex is not the right tool to deal with this task. It might work for tightly controlled one-off scripts, but it will never be reliable enough to use it unattended. You've been warned. :)

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, you have been a big help and reduced work load for myself. I understand the warning and use a beyond compare tool to validate the changes.

Comment: That's a sensible approach.